# Qual a relação entre o ajax do Primefaces e os eventos

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

Diante de certos problemas durante meus desenvolvimentos me surgiu a seguinte dúvida por exemplo.

Quando utilizo a tag `ajax` no `Primefaces`, tem a propriedade `event` onde passamos eventos, então me surgiu um certo questionamento.

Certa vez precisei dar um jeito de ao clicar em `checkbox` selecionar todos, utilizei o evento `click` e a função me retornava um evento via parâmetro desta função.

Agora trabalhando com `datatable` com propriedade de editar os dados nela própria, eu utilizei eventos do tipo `rowEditInit` e `rowEditCancel`, pois o tabela criada contem um botão para editar os dados e outro para deletar, e logico que pensei, se a pessoa esta editando, seria bom bloquear o botão excluir, claro que isso vai de pensamento para pensamento e isso não esta me discussão.

E ai tentei usar a passagem de parâmetro nesta função de habilitar e desabilitar o botão mas não encontrava o evento, então me surgiu a duvida, estes eventos são do `Jquery`, são do `Primefaces`?

Onde estão documentados? Vi no manual o `rowEdit`, `rowEditInit` e `rowEditCancel` mas não tem quais os parâmetros a serem trabalhados.

Tenho esta dúvida e também uma forma de deixa para demais colegas de fórum conhecerem pois acho que isso pode ajudar.

Answer (score 4):

Sua pergunta é muito pertinente, pois o primefaces é um framework de componentes que ao ser renderizado pelo JSF resulta em html, js e jquery no browser do cliente.
Portanto na prática os eventos podem ser do componente padrão html, do JQuery ou até mesmo adicionados pelo próprio primefaces.

Você pode usar qualquer um desses eventos junto a tag `ajax`, porém é sempre uma boa prática utilizar apenas aqueles que estão listados na documentação dos componentes.

No caso dos eventos `rowEdit`, `rowEditInit`, `rowEditCancel`, eles são *Ajax Behavior Events* fornecidos pelo primefaces, o melhor local para encontrar a lista de eventos, parametros e métodos da Client Side API é no user guide oficial do primefaces, nesse endereço existem todas as versões: http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html

Os eventos citados recebem como parametro de listner a classe: `org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu percebi algo neste sentido, mas devido a falta de experiencia procurei opinião dos colegas do SO.